# скрол страницы при движении объекта

Tags: javascript, dom

Нужно чтобы при движении объекта по мере его движения страница скролилась за ним, как можно реализовать в js

Comment: behavior smooth оч быстро скроллит

Comment: приведите минимально воспроизводимый код

Comment: @DaniilLoban https://github.com/dxsya/lift можешь чекнуть так

Comment: @dxsya ну и почему это не подходит? К слову, вы случаем не пропускали главу где учат циклам? Просто судя по коду так оно и есть.

Comment: @ΝNL993 потому что у меня транзишины стоят у анимаций, а бехейвор смус скролит всегда за определенное время ~0,75 сек, ничо я не пропускал

Comment: @dxsya я про события говорил :), у вас на каждую кнопку отдельное событие, а можно было через [делегирование событий](//google.com/search?q=делегирование событий) или в конце концов просто используя индекс назначать конкретной кнопке конкретное событие (Пример: `for (let i ...) { floorBtn[i]...lftFloor.toFloor(i)... }`). Старайтесь чаще использовать циклы, они невероятно ускоряют вашу работу.

Comment: @ΝNL993 я уже закинул все в функцию и добавил скролл через джэйкуери, можно закрывать по идее

Comment: На самом деле и в коде jQuery можно сократить запись (`for (let i ..) { $('#btn'+i) .. $('#fl'+i) .. }`), круто что вы не ленитесь. Кстати, чтобы получить offset top в ванильном js, нужно использовать данную пропорцию: `someElement.offsetTop`, просто говорю чтоб вы знали.  `можно закрывать по идее` Ну получается так, раз вы разобрались, можете опубликовать ответ, главное публикуйте не только код, но ещё и объяснение. Так шанс того что ваш ответ *не* заминусуют повысятся, к тому же скорее всего на него поставят плюс, к слову репутация вам даёт доп. возможности [см. в справке](/help/privileges).